# Is there a way to figure out which web page is associated with which query?

Tags: php, mysql, lamp, sleep

I'm running a LAMP stack.  When I go into phpmyadmin, I can see that there are quite a number of sleeping connections which probably should be closed.  Is there a way, using either Apache or MySQL, to determine on which pages those connections are created?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to log some details from PHP scripts, the following might help:

1. [mysql_thead_id](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-thread-id.php)
2. [$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']](http://ru.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php)
3. [$_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']](http://ru.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php)

Then you can trace the hanging connections seen from phpmyadmin.